# Applying cookie returned from REST api call via GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, express-graphql

When implementing an auth GraphQL module a resolver calls an external API via RESTDataSource.

```
async logout() {
 return await this.post('/logout', { credentials: 'include' })
}
```

This return an empty body object (expected) and headers that include `* Set-Cookie: access_token=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

The expected result is that the `access_token` cookie is deleted from the browser. If this is called directly using fetch then it happens but not when done via GraphQL.

Here is the setup:

```
# Resolver
Mutation: {
    logout: async (_parent, _args, context) => {
      const api = context.injector.get(UserAPI);
      const response = await api.logout();
      return response;
    },
  },
```

and the server...

```
# Apollo Server
function apolloGraphqlServer(app: Express) {
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ req }): { token: string } => {
      return {
        token: req.headers.authorization,
      };
    },
    introspection: true,
  });

  server.applyMiddleware({ app });
}
```

and the client (on Express)

```
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      link: new SchemaLink({
        schema,
        context: {
          session: req,
          token: authCookie ? `Bearer ${authCookie}` : null,
        },
      }),
      credentials: 'include',
      ssrMode: true,
    });
```

How do I get the cookie to delete given the response

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with passing the response into the context...

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ req, res }): { token: string; res: Response } => {
      return {
        token: req.headers.authorization,
        res,
      };
    },
  });
```

and then in the datasource, intercepting the received response and setting the header if available.

```
# datasource

didReceiveResponse(response: Response, request: Request) {
    if (response.headers.get('set-cookie')) {
      this.context.res.set('set-cookie', response.headers.get('set-cookie'));
    }

    return super.didReceiveResponse(response, request);
  }
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution but works for now